# Need help to delete and rename set of directories using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch programming. 
I tried below logic which will check if there is Junk_old exists, if yes- it will delete the directory else it will rename Junk to Junk_old.

```
IF EXIST "E:\Users\Junk_old" ( rd /s /q "E:\Users\Junk_old" ) else (MOVE /Y "E:\Users\Junk" "E:\Users\Junk_old")
```

I need help in doing the same with set of directories in a given path.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You know that will delete `junk_old` even if `junk` doesn't exist?  You will need to provide some details to get help that applies to your situation.

Comment: What exactly i need is
1. Check if Junk_old exists- if yes delete it
2. Else rename the Junk to Junk_old

The intention is to delete the old files and rename the existing files as old.

Comment: That's what your batch code does.  It will also delete your secondary backup, even if your primary backup doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank You.
Yes it does that.
But i need the same to be done for more than one folder.
Ex: if junk1_old junk2_old and junk3_old exists delete them.And Rename the existing junk1, junk2 and junk3 to junk1_old, junk2_old and junk3_old

Answer (score 0):

This will not delete `_old` directory unless a new version of the directory exists.

If output to console is correct, remove the `echo` commands from `rmdir` and `ren`lines

```
@echo off
    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions

    rem Configure paths
    set "root=d:\temp"

    rem For each directory in root that has no "_old" suffix    
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad /b "%root%" ^| findstr /v /e "_old"') do (
        rem If there is an _old version of the directory, remove it
        if exist "%root%\%%~d_old" (
            echo rmdir /s /q "%root%\%%~d_old" 
        )
        rem If there is no _old version of the directory, rename it
        if not exist "%root%\%%~d_old" (
            echo ren "%root%\%%~d" "%%~d_old" 
        )
    )

    rem Clean
    endlocal
```

Comment: This is renaming/deleting all directories from root.
I need to rename and delete set of directories from the given root.
help me in doing that

Comment: @NagaJyotsna: If list of directories is known, change the `for` line with: `for %%d in ("dir1" "dir2" "dir3" "dir4") do (` . If the list is long, better include list of directories in text file and use something like `for /f "tokens=*" %%d in (fileWithListOfDirectories.txt) do (`. In both cases, directories should not include path, as it is being added inside the code. Or change the code to not include %root% and put the path in the directories. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Please help in understanding the script at tilde symbol

Comment: @NagaJyotsna: see `for /?` for a complete list of variable sintax options. In this case, `%%~d` is just the content of `%%d` but without surrounding quotes if present.

Comment: Ok.Got it. Why do we need to use %%d here rather than %d

Comment: @NagaJyotsna: In command line, variables in for loop are referenced as `%d`, but inside batch files the syntax is `%%d`.